# How to sum a property of Marionette/Backbone collection in ItemView template?

Tags: javascript, typescript, backbone.js, underscore.js, marionette

(Using Marionette 1.8.3/Backbone.js/Underscore.js and TypeScript.)

I have an ItemView.

this ItemView has a model:

```
export class M1 extends backbone.Model {
    content: MContent = new MContent();
    ...
}
```

The model has a property that is a Collection:

```
export class MContent extends backbone.Collection<MContentGroup> {
    model: MContentGroup;
    ...
}
```

The collection is a collection of the following model which has a "Count" property:

```
export class MContentGroup extends backbone.Model {
    idAttribute: string = "id";
    constructor(...) {
        ...
        this.set("Count", Math.max(count, 0));
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

In my ItemView template, I would like to display the sum of the Count properties.

From some searches, it appear that using Underscore's reduce() is recommanded for that, but I'm not sure how I am suppose to refer to my collection and its count in this syntax:

```
_.reduce(this? Content?, function(memo, Count){ return memo + Count; }, 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand well you want the sum of the count property of all your model in your collection.

I would use MyCollection.toJSON() which will give you an array of your models (http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-toJSON)

Then loop on the array and sum it (with reduce for example)

```
var MyModels = MyCollection.toJSON();
var sum = _.reduce(MyModels, function(model, countSum) {
    return countSum + model.count;
});
```

Something like that

**Edit:**

As [suggested by Emile Bergeron](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47159336/how-to-sum-a-property-of-marionette-backbone-collection-in-itemview-template#comment81358538_47200164) a better way is to use directly collection methods:

```
myCollection.reduce(function(model, memo) {...})
```

Comment: You don't need `toJSON`, a Backbone [collection proxies ~46 functions from Underscore](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-Underscore-Methods) so you could call `myCollection.reduce(function(model, memo) {...})`.